# unable to validate unchecked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enforce user to give answer if it is 'required EQ true'. 
   this is my form.

```
<p><span class="badge <cfif attributes.required EQ 1>badge-important</cfif>">#attributes.step#</span> <b>#attributes.question#</b></p>
    <fieldset> 
    <div>
        <!--- <span class="span1"></span> --->
    <cfif attributes.yesno>
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="#attributes.type#_#attributes.id#"  id="question_#attributes.id#_yes" value="1">Yes
        </label>
        <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="#attributes.type#_#attributes.id#"  id="question_#attributes.id#_no" value="0">No
        </label>
```

I have tried this but seems no work. can anyone help me out?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          if($('radio').not(':checked')) {
            alert("you must answer this questions");
          }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping that in document.ready? And since there is no event handler, it only runs on pageload!

Comment: Not only that, but you should only run this script AFTER the user tries to submit the form.

Comment: I am executing this snippet in the same form.

Comment: adeneo, i haven't wrapped till now in document.ready.  i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Your JQuery selector is wrong, make it like

```
if($('input[type=radio]').not(':checked')) {
    alert("you must answer this questions");
}
```

Comment: Well, it works for me. the selector as well as condition.
may be there is some other problem. did you try printing to console if the element is found or not?
also try `$('input[type=radio]:not(:checked)')`